# How to cast Datetime that will work in all formats in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datetime, casting

hi i want to cast **Datetime** Column. Actually my system Datetime format is **MM/dd/yyyy**
but client systems contains different different Datetime formats. then how can i search based on Datetime column in SQL.Know i am doing **Converting**

```
  (Datetime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '1980-10-10 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '1990-10-10 00:00:00', 102))
```

but it works when the Client System has Same Format. If the Client System has different DateTime Format.It gives an Error.

Comment: What is "an Error"? Please be explicit instead of hand-wavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YYYYMMDD` will always work, and your client language should be able to use date/time without ever worrying about format anyway. Use a properly parameterized query and you won't have to worry about the format of the string. Also, you shouldn't ever use `BETWEEN` for date ranges, and I don't know why you think you need a `CONVERT` here. The underlying column is `DATETIME` right?

```sql
WHERE column >= '19801010' AND column < '19901011';
```

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)